# How to access Xcode user define build settings from run script in build phase?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, build-automation, build-settings, run-script

I run a script during a build phase.

Xcode lets you define user-defined build settings. I thought I would use these settings to store values  or paths that I want to pass to the script.

Is this possible? How can I pass user-defined build settings to script during the build phase?
Can you point me at some documentation or tutorial?

I am using Xcode 4.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is use the appropriate form of the variable name, depending where you are using it.

Eg: $foo in the run script dialog box.

Comment: do you know how long these vars last? They seem to be gone by the time I access them in my script... :(